# How to reset Rangepicker value via function or via picking the calendar

Tags: reactjs, antd

```
<RangePicker
    value={[ this.state.startTime, this.state.endTime ]}
/>
<Button onClick={ this.clearTime }>clear time</Button>
```

In this way, *clearTime* could clear the RangePicker value. But I could not change the value via picking the calendar

Comment: You RangePicker's value is always going to be based on this.state.startTime and this.state.endTime. Where are you calling this.setState to update the state?

Comment: clearTime = () => { this.setState({ startTime: null, endTime: null }) }

Comment: "I could not change the value via picking the calendar" is your problem that you cannot change the date on the calendar or that you cannot reset the calendar by pressing the button?

Comment: I wanna reset the date both on the calendar and button. In this way it works well via button, but not the calendar.

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code here or in a codepen/ pastebin etc.?